# Is it possible to have a table/view return a scalar value when selecting from it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I am running an SSRS report, and my data source is FetchXML.

Unfortunately, with FetchXML, you are unable to run stored procedures or functions.

This question can be asked several different ways:

1. How do I pass the value of a function into FetchXML?
2. Instead of doing the above, is it possible to just create a table or a view **tbl_finduserGUID** that will return the value of the function **dbo.fn_finduserguid()**?
3. Or Perhaps there's a better way to get the database role of the current user through SSRS / FetchXML?

Here's my query that will be converted to fetchxml:

```
SELECT systemuser.fullname AS 'fullname',
       usersettings.calendartype AS 'calendartype', 
       usersettings.uilanguageid AS 'uilanguageid' 
FROM   filteredsystemuser AS systemuser 
       INNER JOIN filteredusersettings AS usersettings 
               ON systemuser.systemuserid = usersettings.systemuserid 
WHERE  systemuser.systemuserid = dbo.Fn_finduserguid()
```

Here's the source of **dbo.fn_finduserguid()**

```
SET ansi_nulls ON 

go 

SET quoted_identifier ON 

go 

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[Fn_finduserguid] () 
returns UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
AS 
  BEGIN 
      DECLARE @userGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 

      --- test whether the query is runing by priviledged user with user role of CRMReaderRole 
      --- if it is dbo, we trust it as well.  
      --- There is an issue in SQL. If the user is a dbo, if it not member of any role 
      IF ( Is_member('CRMReaderRole') | Is_member('db_owner') ) = 1 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @userGuid = Cast(Context_info() AS UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) 
        END 

      IF @userGuid IS NULL 
        BEGIN 
            SELECT @userGuid = s.systemuserid 
            FROM   systemuserbase s 
            WHERE  s.domainname = Suser_sname() 
        END 

      RETURN @userGuid 
  END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have no problem creating a view that select the function as a column.

```
Create view vFindUserGuid
As
    Select dbo.Fn_finduserguid() as userguid
```

Your query can then use the view like a normal table

```
SELECT systemuser.fullname AS 'fullname',
   usersettings.calendartype AS 'calendartype', 
   usersettings.uilanguageid AS 'uilanguageid' 
FROM   filteredsystemuser AS systemuser 
   INNER JOIN filteredusersettings AS usersettings 
           ON systemuser.systemuserid = usersettings.systemuserid 
WHERE  systemuser.systemuserid = (select userguid from vfinduserguid)
```

Comment: thanks so much, here's what i tried: http://screencast.com/t/hbWvfmYmT  and http://screencast.com/t/8UByawO31

Comment: is there an easy way to rewrite this WITHOUT a where clause (by joining to vfinduserguid?)?

Comment: Yes. You can do a inner join on the view, instead of selecting from it in the where clause

Comment: indeed! it works fine in SSMS, but it breaks crm/ssrs for some reason: http://screencast.com/t/iyPMFgsK

Comment: I'm afraid i can't help you there. ... Are you sure the problem is related? It sounds more like crm is expecting a class or type that doesn't exist?

Comment: i've pintpointed the issue by ONLY selecting from that view: http://screencast.com/t/Hfn7aJA5Y9  it looks like i won't be able to use this view.